# Magento 1.13.1.0 New Website/Store creation Website/Store Name not stored

Tags: admin, magento-1, multistore, ee-1.13, bug

While trying to create a new website via System->Manage Stores on an existing magento install with a website already existing on it. And when editing and existing website/stores name.
The save overwrites the existing name and stores it as null.
[image: screenshot of name not saved]

The same happens for the store save and the store view save.
I have seen this happen on 3 separate installs of this version of enterprise. 
This does not appear to be an issue on the CE equivalent 1.8 at least not 1.8.0.0

This could also be created by similar extension between my different installs.